# How to configure babelify to convert javascript files to IE 11 compatible

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, browserify, babelify

I have a node js library which I would like to reuse within a browser IE 11.

I tried using the following command to convert the code to IE 11 compatible but looks like I am missing some configuration.

```
> browserify Module.js --standalone mymodule -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ @babel/preset-env ] ]
```

I can manually convert the javascript file using https://babeljs.io/repl. How can I automate this?

Comment: Internet Explorer does not support ECMAScript 2015. Given that, why do you need it to output in ES2015 standard?

Comment: looks like my understanding was wrong - thanks for the correction. I would like the script to run in IE 11. How do I configure it? I will update the question too.